# Getting Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException as Sampler response in Jmeter Randomly

Tags: java, networking, jmeter

We are getting **Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException** as sampler response in Jmeter Randomly while executing the complete test.

We want to know the root cause for this issue and want to resolve it. Below are the Sampler request / response details when we get this error.

JMeter Version: 3.3

**Sampler Result:**

`Thread Name: SC05_Create_User 5-1
Sample Start: 2020-01-29 21:17:56 EST
Load time: 0
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 1950
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 1950
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: example.com
Response headers:
HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null`

**Response Data:**

> at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(Unknown Source)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
>   at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(Unknown Source)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.resolveHostname(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:263)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:162)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:318)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:114)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
>   at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:695)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:454)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1189)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1178)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:498)``
>   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:424)
>   at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255)

Comment: Why are you surprised that domain name `mycompany.com` doesn't respond to HTTPS requests? It's an **ISP!** --- The name actually looks like an *example* name, and needs to be replaced with some actual server name.

Comment: Instead of specifying out company website I provided mycompany.com. Now I changed to example.com to avoid confusion.

NOTE: We are getting this error randomly, not everytime.

Comment: Any updates on this issue? Still we are facing this issue randomly.

Comment: Root cause: Your DNS server is not responding in a timely manner.

Comment: Is there any confirmation, because we did not understand whether this is an issue from the application or from the system which we executing JMeter scripts.

Comment: Not the application. Not the system running it. The DNS **server**, like I already said, or the network connecting the system to the DNS server.

Comment: Is there any fix / actions to avoid this issue. We are facing this issue in every run continuously 2 to 3 minutes(all samplers failed due to this issue in that time) randomly. And due to this the error count is increasing.

Comment: Install a local caching DNS server on your network.

Comment: I am not aware of Network, Please provide the steps to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is something your network administrator needs to do. If your network administrator need help, ask on https://serverfault.com/